# Prefix to infix not quite giving the correct result

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a pretty simple algorithm that takes a RPN string and converts it to infix:

```
   for(unsigned int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++)
    {
        token = tokens[i];

        if(!isOperator(token))
        {
            stack.push(token);
        }
        else
        {
            //need at least 2 values
            string a = stack.pop();
            string b = stack.pop();
            string expr = "(" + a + token + b + ")";
            stack.push(expr);
        }
    }

string converted = stack.pop();
```

However, my RPN string also has exponents in it.

Here is a sample RPN:

```
3 4 2 * 1 5 - 2 3 ^ ^ / +
```

Infix looks like:

```
(3+((4*2)/((1-5)^(2^3))))
```

This is correct.

I modified this to work with prefix:

```
for(int i = tokens.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        token = tokens[i];

        if(!isOperator(token))
        {
            stack.push(token);
        }
        else
        {
            //need at least 2 values
            string a = stack.pop();
            string b = stack.pop();
            string expr = "(" + a + token + b + ")";
            stack.push(expr);
        }
    }
```

But it gives a slightly different result:

Given the prefix:

```
+ 3 * 4 / 2 ^ ^ - 1 5 2 3
```

I get the infix:

```
(3+(4*(2/(((1-5)^2)^3))))
```

Which is slightly wrong. I am not sure why the 4 gets multiplied by the other portion of the expression instead of 2.

Could anyone point me to what might be wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your algorithm is correct. You get the wrong answer because your **test input is wrong**.

The prefix for the corresponding infix should be

```
+ 3 / * 4 2 ^ - 1 5 ^ 2 3
```

The information about the [prefix notation](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/cs212/fix.html) (Polish notation) I refereed to.